# Decoding raw bytes received by udp_receive with as( codes )

Tags: prolog, udp, ieee-754

I'm trying to decode myself a list of raw bytes received by `udp_received`.

Two questions:

1. I haven't found any standard means, like ByteBuffer in Java
2. There are errors in `decodeDouble` while `decodeLong` works fine.

Using a standard would be preferable.

Operating on byte list is mandatory to integrate an already built system developed in C/C++ and Java.

Here is the code:

```
decodeLong( [B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7|Remaining], Long, Remaining ) :-
    Long is (B0 << 56)
        \/    (B1 << 48)
        \/    (B2 << 40)
        \/    (B3 << 32)
        \/    (B4 << 24)
        \/    (B5 << 16)
        \/    (B6 <<  8)
        \/    (B7 <<  0).

decodeDouble( [B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7|Remaining], Double, Remaining ) :-
    ((B0 >> 7) > 0 -> Sign = -1 ; Sign = +1),
    Fraction is ((B1 /\ 0x0F) << 48)
        \/        ( B2          << 40)
        \/        ( B3          << 32)
        \/        ( B4          << 24)
        \/        ( B5          << 16)
        \/        ( B6          <<  8)
        \/        ( B7          <<  0),
    Exponent is ((B0 /\ 0x7F) \/ ((B1 /\ 0xE0) >> 5)),
    ExponentBias is 2^( 11 - 1) - 1, % double: 11 bits for Exponent
    format( "Sign    : ~w~n", [Sign]),
    format( "Fraction: ~w~n", [Fraction]),
    format( "Exponent: ~w~n", [Exponent]),
    Double is Sign*Fraction*2^(Exponent-ExponentBias). % see IEEE 754

test :-
    RawBytes = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -123, -64, 94, -36, -52, -52, -52, -52, -51],
    decodeLong( RawBytes, Long, Remaining0 ),
    format( "decodeLong produces: ~w, Remaining: ~w~n", [Long, Remaining0]),
    Long      = -123,
    decodeDouble( Remaining0, Double, Remaining1 ),
    format( "decodeDouble produces: ~w, Remaining: ~w~n", [Double, Remaining1]),
    Double     = -123.45,
    Remaining1 = []. % all bytes has been consumed
```

The execution:

```
?- test.
decodeLong produces: -123, Remaining: [-64,94,-36,-52,-52,-52,-52,-51]
Sign    : 1
Fraction: -51
Exponent: 66
decodeDouble produces: -4.186627537324344e-287, Remaining: []
false.
```

Comment: No need to do this: `[B0|[B1|[B2|Remaining]]]`. This is exactly the same as `[B0,B1,B2|Remaining]`. Try: `?- [X,Y|Z] = [a,b,c,d,e].`

Comment: OK, I prefer your proposal, clear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will be better off using native code to do the conversion from bytes to double.

There are a few edge cases you have to take care otherwise, and reinventing the wheel here does not make much sense.

If you still want to write decoder for floating point numbers then you should read the standard or some page with info for [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)  to add the decoding for denormal numbers and other special values.

Heres is a fix for your decode code. At this point it only works right on normal numbers (like your example):

```
decodeDouble( [B0,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6,B7|Remaining], Double, Remaining ) :-
    ((B0 mod 256 >> 7) > 0 -> Sign = -1 ; Sign = +1),
    Fraction is ((B1 /\ 0x0F) mod 256 << 48)
        \/        ( B2 mod 256         << 40)
        \/        ( B3 mod 256         << 32)
        \/        ( B4 mod 256         << 24)
        \/        ( B5 mod 256         << 16)
        \/        ( B6 mod 256         <<  8)
        \/        ( B7 mod 256         <<  0),
    Significand is 1.0 + Fraction / 2^52,
    Exponent is (((B0 /\ 0x7F mod 256) << 4) \/ ((B1 /\ 0xF0 mod 256) >> 4)),
    ExponentBias is 2^( 11 - 1) - 1, % double: 11 bits for Exponent
    format( "Sign    : ~w~n", [Sign]),
    format( "Fraction: ~w~n", [Fraction]),
    format( "Significand: ~w~n", [Significand]),
    format( "Exponent: ~w~n", [Exponent]),
    Double is Sign*Significand*2^(Exponent-ExponentBias). % see IEEE 754
```

test run:

```
?- test.
decodeLong produces: -123, Remaining: [-64,94,-36,-52,-52,-52,-52,-51]
Sign    : -1
Fraction: 4183421841362125
Significand: 1.92890625
Exponent: 1029
decodeDouble produces: -123.45, Remaining: []
true.
```

You had a few errors. You start with "bytes" in the range [-128, 127]. I moved it to the range [0,255] to apply the binary operations.
You also got some shiftings off by 1, the computation of the significand was wrong (forgot the implicit 1 and to make the fraction an actual fraction)

You may easily enhance the procedure to deal with denormal numbers. You would need to also take care of the varios special values the standard provides

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I have written a small DatagramSocket library, in C, which is loaded by my Prolog scripts successfully.